# Socket.io. Is it possible sending to individual socketid (private message) by socket id without specifying namespace?

Tags: socket.io

Can I sending to individual socketid (private message) by socket id without specifying namespace?

Sample: `socket.to(socketId).emit('message')` . It does not work for me.

It work only with namespace.  `namespaceIo.to(socketId).emit('message')`

Is it possible sending to individual socketid (private message) by socket id without specifying namespace? Because all the same socket id is global for server.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "direct messages".  That's not a standard socket.io term.

Comment: @jfriend00
I mean - sending to individual socketid (private message)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send a message on the server directly to a single socket when you have just that socket's ID value, you can do this:

```
io.to(socketId).emit('message');
```

In this case, `io` works like the top level namespace.

Comment: Yes, i know. But i have multiple namespaces. And i want sending to individual socketid (private message) **without** specifying namespace. Is it possible? Your example work only with default ('/') namespace.

Comment: @YuryGolikov - You're confusing me.  Is the target socket in a specific namespace or not?  I don't think socket.io keeps a global list of all sockets regardless of namespace.  They keep lists of sockets in a specific namespace.  That's the ENTIRE point of a namespace (to maintain separate lists of sockets).

Comment: yes. I have multiple namespaces. In one of them - socket. Example: /ns1 and /ns2. I have socket id. But a don't know namespace of this socket. Can i sending to individual socket id (private message) knowing only socket id?

Comment: but why they made socket id with global name?                     
 Like /ns1#iQYAFwMHhxjDL-4dAAAC ? for what?

Comment: @YuryGolikov - It sounds like maybe you should be using only a single namespace and then use rooms to group sockets.  Then, you can send to any socket or a group of sockets more easily.  namespaces are just more separated than you are trying to make them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the namespace if you're sending to another socket in the same namespace, which is what should be the case. If not then you should consider using rooms instead. Here is a basic example:

```
# server side
var nsp = io.of('/foo');

nsp.on('connection', function (socket) {

  // Broadcast new connection to everyone except the sender in namespace foo
  socket.broadcast.emit('new-socket-connection', socket.id);

  socket.on('response', function(data) {
    socket.to(data.responseId).emit('message', data.msg);
  });

});
```

Where `responseId` is the same id sent in `'new-socket-connection'`